# Function across 3 dataframes at same index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is it possible to do a function across 3 dataframes A, B and C along the same index? The end dataframe will have the same dimensions as DF A. For example:

```
def func(dfA.A0, dfB.A0, dfC.A0):
    if (dfA.A0 > dfB.A0):
        return dateDifferenceBetween(dfA.A0, dfC.A0)
    return 0

    Dataframe A         
    ABC DEF GHI JKL
01/01/2017  12/11/2017  03/01/2017  26/03/2017  10/07/2017
01/02/2017  21/08/2017  28/02/2017  08/09/2017  07/03/2017
01/03/2017  15/09/2017  07/01/2017  24/07/2017  15/11/2017
01/04/2017  01/01/2017  29/10/2017  13/06/2017  10/05/2017

    Dataframe B         
    ABC DEF GHI JKL
01/01/2017  22/11/2017  12/01/2017  08/04/2017  22/07/2017
01/02/2017  31/08/2017  11/03/2017  20/09/2017  14/03/2017
01/03/2017  26/09/2017  13/01/2017  05/08/2017  19/11/2017
01/04/2017  09/01/2017  02/11/2017  25/06/2017  21/05/2017


    Dataframe C         
    0           
01/01/2017  22/11/2017          
01/02/2017  31/08/2017          
01/03/2017  26/09/2017          
01/04/2017  09/01/2017
```

[image]

Comment: But C doesn't have the same shape...

Comment: i can duplicate the column to be the same as dataframe a and b

Comment: was wondering if it was possible to not require doing that

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Take a look at my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you can iterate over the columns of `A` and `B` and pass it to a function:

```
for i range(len(A.columns)):
    func(A.iloc[:, i], B.iloc[:, i], C.iloc[:, 0])
```

Keep in mind this approach works even if `A`, `B`, and `C` all have different column names.

Furthermore, `func` will now be accepting 3 `pd.Series` as arguments:

```
def func(sA, sB, sC):
    ...
```

Comment: hey, thanks for the answer. but im getting a slice error doing this.

`import pandas as pd`

`pd.DataFrame(a)`
`Out[48]: `
`    0  1  2`
`0  1  2  3`
`1  4  5  6`
`2  7  8  9`

`for i in range(len(a.columns)):`
` test(a[:,i], b[:,i])`

Comment: res = cache.get(item)

TypeError: unhashable type: 'slice'

Comment: @smallcat31 You are pointing to errors in your code that you did not show here. I'm sorry but I can't help you. The understanding behind an MCVE is that you would be able to apply the solution to your actual code on your own, if that wasn't possible then you should've provided all your code from the start.

Comment: `a=pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])`
`b=pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]])`
`for i in range(len(a.columns)):`
` test(a[:,i], b[:,i])`

Comment: @smallcat31 What aren't you using `df.iloc` _like my answer mentions_? `test(a.iloc[:,i], b.iloc[:,i])` Cmon dude... copy my answer right...

Comment: `def test(a,b): return a+b`

Comment: so sorry! my bad. Thanks for your help!